# Why does GS segment selector value does not change after SWAPGS instruction? (windows kernel debugging)

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, windows-kernel, msr

I'm trying to learn how the kernel works, during the process, using WinDbg, i have put a breakpoint at the Page Fault handler, after "swapgs" and "lfence" instructions:
[Page Fault Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8RHT.png)
After I resume execution and WinDbg breaks, GS value stays the same (0x2B).

I tried reading the "MSR_KERNEL_GS_BASE" (0xC0000102) with rdmsr, and examining the memory around GS:[9018h], but it is uninitialized:
[Memory at GS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGVPF.png)

(I also tried converting physical to virtual address (!ptov 0xDB3A0CF018), thinking that might be the case. no success.)
Yet after stepping through, the Bit Test instruction sets the Carry Flag.

Now than, what am I missing?
Why GS does not update in WinDbg?
Why does the memory around GS from the MSR cant be read?
What's happening behind the scenes in the case of "**bt      dword ptr gs:[9018h], 1**"?
Is there a way to read the kernel memory that is being tested?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't post images of WinDbg output. WinDbg produces text which you can insert here, formatted as code.

Comment: Reading the GS MSRs is quite unreliable with Windbg (e.g. if you're in CPL3 context and read MSR_GS_BASE, you might get a kernel address or the other way around with  MSR_KERNEL_GS_BASE). The GDT entry is also not reliable since it relies on a "hidden descriptor field"  (related to the GS MSRs) as told by the intel manuals. Best way to get the base of the GS segment is to use the `? @$pcr` or `!pcr` commands. They both output the address of the `_KPCR` (kernel processor control region) which is meant to be pointed by GS. Be wary that it is **per-processor** and not system wide.